# How to fix 'TypeError: Cannot call method "getMessages" of undefined.'

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, typeerror

I just joined a company and I'm having issues with a script written by someone who no longer works here.  I keep receiving a TypeError.  I'm also new to this code.

I've gone through some other threads and didn't see anything related to this particular TypeError.

```
function csatGmailPull() {

  var threads = GmailApp.search("label: name");
  var message = threads[0].getMessages()[0];
  var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0];

  if (attachment.getContentType() === "text/csv") {

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SheetID").getSheetByName('Import');
    var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(attachment.getDataAsString(), ",");

    sheet.clearContents().clearFormats();
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);

    var labelOld = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("LabelName");
    var labelNew = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("LabelName2");

    threads[0].addLabel(labelNew);
    threads[0].removeLabel(labelOld);

}
}
```

I've removed the sheet ID and label names.  But this code is supposed to open up Gmail, get the emails under the label identified in the GmailApp.search, load the data into a preset Google Spreadsheet, and then tag the message with a new label.  However, I keep getting "TypeError: Cannot call method "getMessages" of undefined." when I test it.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The error says that `threads[0]` is undefined, which suggests that the search for `label: name` doesn't yield any results.

Comment: Ah ok, so when no messages in the inbox match the label, it returns that error.  So the code is fine.  Thanks!

Comment: The code is basically fine, but you should add `if (threads.length === 0) return;` I guess.

Comment: Ideally, the code should first check the length and handle the case where the list is empty.

Comment: @GaloisGirl, that's a good idea.  I believe Chris' addition does just that.  I inserted the line right after the var threads, and it works just fine.

Comment: Is there a reason you're only getting the first thread in the results? What if there are multiple threads in that label?  You could process all of the threads/messages by iterating through all of them: `GmailApp.search("label: name").forEach(function(thread){thread.getMessages().forEach(function(message){...});});`

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan True, but this is done intentionally.  Based on the way the source system puts out the info, we only ever need the first (latest) thread.